# Problems with behaviors in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, behavior

I have a problem in one of my projects, where I'm using Doctrine as an ORM.

For some reason, when rebuilding the models and database structure, Doctrine ignores the behaviors and relations, I define in one of the table definitions. The YAML table definition looks like this:

```
...

User:  
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      fields: username
      canUpdate: true
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    company_id
      type: integer(4)
    timezone_id:
      type: integer(1)
    role_id:
      type: integer(1)
    email:
      type: string(255)
    username:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    password:
      type: string(40)
    firstname:
      type: string(255)
    lastname:
      type: string(255)
    last_login:
      type: datetime
  relations:
    Company:
      local: company_id
      foreign: id
    Timezone:
      local: timezone_id
      foreign: id
    Role:
      local: role_id
      foreign: id

...
```

The generated table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see, Doctrine generates all the columns I define, but for some reason all the stuff that is supposed to happen automatically is not done. First of all, it doesn't create the `updated_at` and `created_at` columns for the Timestampable behavior and the `slug` column for Sluggable behavior is also missing.

The indexes and foreign key constraints are also missing.

When I open up the generated model class, it looks all fine:

```
class BaseUser extends Doctrine_Record
{

    ....

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Company', array(
             'local' => 'company_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));

        $this->hasOne('Timezone', array(
             'local' => 'timezone_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));

        $this->hasOne('Role', array(
             'local' => 'role_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));

        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable();
        $sluggable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Sluggable(array(
             'unique' => true,
             'fields' => 'username',
             'canUpdate' => true,
        ));
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
        $this->actAs($sluggable0);
    }

    ....

}
```

So, the problem lies in the SQL query generation...

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem, or can you spot any errors in my YAML definition?

Comment: What happens if you write `Timestampable: ~` ?

Comment: It's the same result. :/ 

I have defined the behaviors in the same way on many other models, and it works perfectly on them. There must something I do wrong with the User model...

Comment: Hmm... Weird... If I rename the model to `Person` and rebuild, it's working perfectly!? - Maybe I should submit a bug-report to the Doctrine team.

Comment: Well at least you figured out a way to solve it ;)

Comment: Hehe, yeah :P - I've created a ticket in the Doctrine bugtracker, to let them know about the problem... But thank's for your help! :)

Comment: You question helped to solve [my one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617301/table-creaction-on-doctrine-migration-for-custom-behavior). %)

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you posted, and the subsequent comments, it appears there is name collision with your `User` table, and the `mysql`.`user` table. As you mentioned when you renamed your table to `Person`, it worked as expected.

In my experience, I always add an arbitrary table prefix to my tables to avoid these types of unexpected behaviors.